# Force loop to wait for mysql insert before moving to next iteration

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a loop that runs and inserts records into a mysql database for each iteration. The problem is that I think async is screwing up the writing to the db. If i have a 10 iteration loop, only 8 of the inserts are being recorded (for example).
I'm trying to find a way to make the loop wait for the update to occur before going on to the next iteration of the loop. Here's the code:

```
var queryString1 = "insert into expense_summary "+
  "(user_id, customer_id, expense_date, category, cost) values (?,?,?,?,?)"
  connection.query(queryString1, [
    detail[0].employee, 
    detail[0].customer, 
    detail[0].date, 
    detail[0].category, 
    detail[0].total], function(err, result) {
      var summaryId = result.insertId;
      console.log("This is the summary ID" + summaryId);

      var data;
      for (i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
        var queryString = "insert into expense_detail "+
          "(expense_summary_id, expense_date, line_id, item_name, description, cost_per, quantity, tax, user_id, customer_id, expense_category_id, ad_hoc, reimbursable) "+
          "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        connection.query(queryString, [
          summaryId, 
          detail[i].date, 
          detail[i].line, 
          detail[i].item, 
          detail[i].description, 
          detail[i].cost,
          detail[i].quantity, 
          detail[i].tax, 
          detail[i].employee, 
          detail[i].customer, 
          detail[i].category, 
          detail[i].adHoc, 
          detail[i].reimbursable], function(err, result) {
            if(err){
              throw err;
            } else{
              console.log(result);
            }
          });   
       }
    });
```

Comment: From your code, there doesn't seem to be any reasons why you would need to wait between inserts. However, if you still want to do this, have a look at `async / await`.

Comment: `I'm trying to find a way to make the loop wait for the update to occur before going on to the next iteration of the loop.` This is what you do, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async/await if you using latest node.js > 8.

```js
(async  () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                console.log(i);
                await new Promise (resolve => setTimeout (resolve, 500))
        }
})();
```

Wrap your whole function in the promise and replace that with timeout promise.

Or you can use a modern for … of loop instead, in which await will work as expected:

```
async function query() {
  for (let d of detail) {
    const contents = await your_query_promise();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first option worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Ridham. I still need to look further into relationship between async/await. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the typical problem with variables and scopes. 
Just try changing these 2 lines:

```
for (let i=0; i<detail.length; i++){

    let queryString = "insert into expense_detail "+
                      "(expense_summary_id, expense_date, line_id, item_name, description, cost_per, quantity, tax, user_id, customer_id, expense_category_id, ad_hoc, reimbursable) "+
                      "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Declaring varibales with let you avoid sharing the variable values among the different iterations